# tablesorter td-colspan in tbody

Tags: jquery, sorting, nested, html-table, tablesorter

I am trying to use tablesorter-plugin to sort my table with consist of rows where the last cell is spanning over multiple columns.

In the spanning column, there is a inner-table, which is holding multiple cells and hidden row(s). When sorting table header 1 response to column 1, table header 2 response to column 2 and table header 3 response the spanning column and the textExtraction sorts the spanning column. But there are more table-headers and they should sort on the inner-table, rather than on the next column.

I've made a little example here: http://jsfiddle.net/frankmyhre/aoLgu7f9/

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction: {
        1: function(node){ return $(node).find('.cell1').eq(0).text(); },
        2: function(node){ return $(node).find('.cell2').eq(0).text(); }
    }
});
```

**To simplify it, this is what i'm trying to obtain (from the fiddle):**

The "Name"-header sorts the name-column (column 0)
The "Phone"-header sorts the spanning-column (column 1) by looking at the value of the first occurence of cell1-class
The "Type"-header sorts the spanning-column (column 1) by looking at the value of the first occurence of cell2-class

Comment: Currently, if a `colspan` is encountered in the `tbody`, tablesorter uses the [`duplicateSpan` setting](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#duplicatespan) to either set that cell's value to the same for all spanned cells, or an empty string. I'll need to update the function to make it call the `textExtraction` function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fork of tablesorter has been update to use the `textExtraction` function if set instead of setting the cell value to an empty string when the `duplicateSpan` option is set to `false` ([docs](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#duplicatespan)) - but this change is currently only available in the master branch of the repository and is set to be released with version 2.25.8.

So, you can do this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/aoLgu7f9/19/), using [this file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
  debug: true,
  duplicateSpan: false,
  textExtraction: function(node, table, cellIndex) {
    if (cellIndex > 0) {
      // this works because cell1 and cell2 match the table
      // column zero-based index
      return $(node).find('.cell' + cellIndex).eq(0).text(); 
    }
    return node.textContent;
  }
});
```

Note: this method uses the `textExtraction` function to grab data from the first cell1 or cell2, so the cells with "home" are ignoring the "club" and "office" content. If you want to include that then modify the function as follows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/aoLgu7f9/20/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
  duplicateSpan: false,
  textExtraction: function(node, table, cellIndex) {
    if (cellIndex > 0) {
      // this works because cell1 and cell2 match the table
      // column zero-based index
      var txt = '';
      $(node).find('.cell' + cellIndex).each(function(){
        txt += this.textContent + ' ';
      });
      return txt;
    }
    return node.textContent;
  }
});
```

Note 2: the `debug` option is `true` in the demos so you can look at the console and see the difference in these two functions.

Comment: Hey mottie, thanks for the great reply, it worked perfect. I tried adding an extra column to the table (not in the nested one) and thought it would work if I changed the index from 0 to 1, but it only sorts on the first (ID) and third (column) see http://jsfiddle.net/frankmyhre/aoLgu7f9/. I can see in the debug that if I put add the ID-column, the type-column isn't present.

Comment: The "cell1" and "cell2" class names need to match the column they are in, so change those classes to "cell2" and "cell3" respectively - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/aoLgu7f9/23/).

Comment: Fantastic Mottie, thanks. And thank you for the great examples you have made for the tablesorter-plugin